# Why was this question deleted despite having no issues as far as I can see?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Some days ago someone asked [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756325/) which was genuine. I don't know, but why was it deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can see the question at all, you should see

1. A deletion notice saying "This post is hidden. It was deleted last month by Community (Bot)."
2. That the user that asked the question no longer exists.

Some ways of deleting users delete some or all of their posts with them, and that is what happened here, in particular "destruction" of an account (point 13 [in this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/263383)) deletes all posts and comments associated with the account. User deletion may happen on request of the user (this usually does not result in destruction) or for moderatorial reasons, but in either case we generally do not make the specific reasons for user deletion public unless it seems absolutely necessary.

If users with [sufficient reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) consider this question useful enough that it should be undeleted, they can vote to undelete it.